# C++ Instances of value in array? (Histogram)

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if it was possible in C++ to parse through an array and retrieve the amount of times an integer appears in the array.   I'm trying to make a histogram of the values, but currently am stuck as to how to continue.

It is a one-dimensional array if that matters and I am using this function to print the array:

```
void print(int a[], int n)
{
    int j = 1;

    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(!(j%6)) 
        {
            j=1; cout << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << right << setw(2) << a[i] << " "; 
        ++j; 

    }
}
```

Which is giving me correct output in this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vFrB.png

However, once I go to my histogram function (which I know is coded incorrectly) I am getting the following output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7BDF.png

Because with my current code it is printing asterisks based on a value taken from the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << a[i] << ":" << bar(a[i-1]);
    cout << endl;
}
```

P.S. - The "bar" function just returns a string with a specified amount of '*' based on the number given to it.

I know the last bit is incorrect, but that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: `a[i-1]` is accessing element indexed `-1`

Comment: I've tried quite a bit, my submission doesn't really show that as I just threw something in to see what it would do.  I'm more versed in python, but that approach doesn't seem to be helping.  Attempting other methods now.

Comment: What is the range of integers it may contain?

Comment: I ask because if the range is known to be sufficiently narrow you can use a histogram array where indices represent integers from the primary array, and the values in the histogram array represent how many times the integer represented by the index is seen in the primary array. By throwing memory at the problem you end up with a solution that avoids the computational overhead of the hashing algorithm used by unordered map, or avoid the expensive sort requirement... if you can spare the memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figured it out.  Not entirely sure if its efficient but it is functional which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to go:

1. sort+count

   1. Sort the array
   2. Iterate through them all, and print summaries on encountering a different element / the end.
2. unordered_map

   1. Create an `std::unordered_map<int,int>`
   2. Iterate through the array incrementing the count for each encountered element when you encounter it.
   3. Print the summary.

An array of size 2**`sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` is prohibitively big.

Comment: I have the array sorted, I will attempt to write something that goes along with your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. You can keep a map with the counts of each element, being each element a key to the map:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    int current = a[i];
    //if it doesn't find it  it returns 
    if (countMap.find(current) != countMap.end())end()
    {
      countMap[current]++;
    } else
    {
      countMap[current] = 1;
    }    
  }
```

I don't know if the syntax is totally correct, but something like this will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
int tempVal = 0;
int tempTwo = 0;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // Checks for histogram output
{
    tempVal = a[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] == tempVal)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }

    }
if(tempVal != tempTwo)
    cout << setw(3) << tempVal << " : " << bar(counter) << endl;
    tempTwo = tempVal;
    counter = 0;
}
```